# Norm of operator in finite element discretization of Heat equation

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element, pde, finite-difference, matrix

I am solving the heat equation discretized spatially via FEM and temporally via backward Euler.
I get the system 
$$M \dot{u} = K u +f$$ where $u$ is a vector representing the solution at spatial locations.

For piecewise linear basis functions, the mass matrix is defined as
[image]
while the stiffness matrix $K$ is
[image]

By discretizing this in time, I get
$$u_{k+1} = Au_k + By_k$$
for some matrix $B.$ Here, $A = (I-\Delta t M^{-1}K)^{-1}$ where $\Delta t$ is the time step size.

Is it possible to show that $$\|A\|_2 < 1$$ for $\Delta t$ sufficiently small? I would like an analytical solution without computing this in Matlab.

I have a hard time analyzing this because $M^{-1}K$ is not symmetric although $M,K$ are symmetric. Otherwise, I could have just used the fact that the spectral radius and the 2 norm coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stability analysis, we can assume $f = 0$. First we write
$$
M \left( u_{k+1} - u_{k} \right) = \Delta t K u_{k+1}
$$
or
$$
\left( M - \Delta t K \right) u_{k+1} = M u_{k}
$$
Take the eigendecomposition of $(K, M)$ (there is an [explicit expression in 1D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative)), such that
$$
w_i^T K w_j = \delta_{ij} \lambda_i \quad \mbox{and} \quad
w_i^T M w_j = \delta_{ij}
$$ 
Write
$$
w_i^T \left( M - \Delta t K \right) u_{k+1} = w_i^T M u_{k}
$$
and express $u_k$ and $u_{k+1}$ in the basis of eigenmodes.
From there, you should be able to get an analytical expression to control $\Delta t$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am confused about 2 things:
1) I'm not interested in showing stability but rather I want to show that $\|A\|_2 < 1$. Does the approach you mentioned above work for this or is it only to show that the spectral radius is less than 1? 2) What do you mean by express $u_k,u_{k+1}$ as eigenmodes? I have never heard of the method you showed above before. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: 1. Why do you want to show that $||A||_2 < 1$? --- 2. $u_k = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \mu_k^j w_j$. Using the orthogonality among the eigenvectors $(w_i)$, we get an expression between $\mu_{k+1}^{j}$ and $\mu_{k}^{j}$.

Comment: Note also
 $|| ( I - M^{-1} K )^{-1} x ||_2 
 = || ( M^{-1/2} ( I - M^{-1/2} K M^{-1/2} ) M^{+1/2} )^{-1} x ||_2  
 = || M^{-1/2} ( I - M^{-1/2} K M^{-1/2} )^{-1} M^{+1/2} x ||_2
 = || ( I - M^{-1/2} K M^{-1/2} )^{-1} M^{+1/2} x ||_{M^{-1}}$

Comment: I'm using it for error estimates. How does the above help in finding the 2-norm of $I-\Delta t M^{-1}K$?

Comment: When you use the expression with $M^{-1}$-norm, the operator $I - \Delta t M^{-1/2} K M^{-1/2}$ is now symmetric and its eigenvectors are the ones of $(K, M)$. So studying $|| ( I - \Delta t M^{-1} K )^{-1} x ||_2 / || x ||_{2}$ is the same as studying $|| ( I - \Delta t M^{-1/2} K M^{-1/2})^{-1} y ||_{M^{-1}} / || y ||_{M^{-1}}$ (where $y = M^{1/2} x$)

Comment: @user1237300, thanks for your suggestion! I'll work on it. Last question: How is $$\|(I - \Delta t M^{-1/2} KM^{-1/2})^{-1}\|_{M^{-1}}/\|y\|_{M^{-1}}$$ related to the eigenvectors of $(K,M)$? What do you mean by $(K,M)$? Did you refer to the eigenvalues of $(I - \Delta t M^{-1/2} KM^{-1/2})^{-1}$? Is there any website that you can point me to learn more about this? Thanks!

Comment: The generalized eigenvalue problem with pencil $(K,M)$ is $Kx=Mx \lambda$ (where $K$ is symmetric and $M$ is symmetric pos. definite). There exists a basis made of eigenvectors $x$ such that $X^TKX$ is diagonal and $X^TMX$ is equal to the identity matrix. Here is a reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11240.pdf  Note that if $Kx_i=Mx_i \lambda_i$, then you have $M^{-1/2}KM^{-1/2}(M^{1/2}x_i)=(M^{1/2}x_i) \lambda_i$ or $M^{-1/2}KM^{-1/2}v_i=v_i\lambda_i$ (with $v_i=M^{1/2}x_i$). When the columns of $V$ are equal to all $v_i$, we have $V^TM^{-1/2}KM^{-1/2}V$ is diagonal and $V^TV$ is identity

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, really appreciate it!